# How to check if any item in list starts with string and if so how to get item index?

Tags: python

```python
elif any(item.startswith('qwerty') for item in myList):
    itemIndex = myList.index(item)
```

"item" is not defined

I want to assign item's index to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

From Python 3.8 onwards, you can use an [assignment expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) inside `any` to capture the value in the expression.

Something like this:

```
elif any((found:=item).startswith('qwerty') for item in myList):
    itemIndex = myList.index(found)
```

Alternatively, you could replace `any` with [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), which will give you the found value:

```
found = next((item for item in myList if item.startswith('qwerty')), None)
if found is not None:
    itemIndex = myList.index(found)
```

Or you could use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and get the index without needing to look it up separately:

```
index = next((i for (i,item) in enumerate(myList) if item.startswith('qwerty')), None)
```

Comment: I think second code isn't correct:
found = next((item for item in myList if item.startswith('qwerty'), None)

"(" was not closed
"(" was not closed

Comment: @undefined You're right: I missed a `)`. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try something like this

```
elif any([item.startswith("qwerty") for item in myList]):
    itemindex = [myList.index(item) for item in myList if item.startswith("qwerty")]
```